# SQL injection using PMD

Tags: java, security, sql-injection, findbugs, pmd

I am stuck with a situation where **FindBugs** couldn't  able to detect **SQL injection** in my project. The project contains multiple-repo with gradle. Is there any way I can identify with the help of **PMD**? Or if you have any alternative please suggest me.

Comment: Don't expect a tool to find all problems with your code. In tricky cases they can only use some heuristics. Making the rules too strict will lead to a lot of false positives. It is maybe better to do some code reviews.

Comment: But @Henry, in FindBugs doc  section it is clearly stated that it can handle SQL injection but it is not doing what it is suppose to do, I don't know why but it is okay. How SQL injection can be captured using PMD?

Answer (score 1):

Just so we are all on the same page:

**It is impossible for a tool like PMD to find all SQL injection errors.**

Tools can spot some obviously wrong patterns, but you will not get help above what you can do by hand, by simply searching all your codebase (using grep or an IDE) for strings containing "SELECT", "INSERT" and "UPDATE" and making sure they are not built using concatenation.

The value of PMD and such is not in the intelligence, but to the contrary: their stupid, small-minded stubbornness and insistence that certain patterns are avoided "just in case".

Answer (score 0):

SQL injection is mostly vul. for your login portal and links open with ?id or something like that, and I guess you don't need any tool get it patch in Java. Sql-Injection & Blind SQL both attack cause due to careless code implementation with JDBC.

Quick fix will be, update all of your existing db call with **PrepareStatement** and if you have open URL for ID then apply proper encp/decp on that.

Comment: I am very cautious with my code, but some how I want to capture SQL injection if any in my code. How to do with PMD?

Comment: PMD will analyze your code. it's upto you how you will resolve all highlighted issues by PMD.

Comment: How to explicitly specify PMD to capture SQL injection?

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have added [Find Security Bugs](http://find-sec-bugs.github.io/)? If not you should, because it could detect some more security risks - also some SQL injection risks. Btw. you should no longer use FindBugs, use its successor [SpotBugs](https://spotbugs.github.io/) - the above plugin works also fine with SpotBugs.